# Integrate $\int {\dfrac{x^2+\left(n-1\right)n}{\left(x\sin x+n\cos x\right)^2}}dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> $$\int {\dfrac{x^2+\left(n-1\right)n}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}}dx $$

My Try:

I multiple $x^{2n-2}$ to both N and D, then took D as $u$ and then solved to get $\dfrac{n\sin\left(x\right)-x\cos\left(x\right)}{x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)} + C$ as answer.

My teacher told that this would have been much easier if we had applied linearity and written question as

$={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{x\sin\left(x\right)+\left(n-1\right)\cos\left(x\right)}{x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\left(\left(1-n\right)\sin\left(x\right)+x\cos\left(x\right)\right)\left(n\sin\left(x\right)-x\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

I didn't get it, how did we write the above statement? I mean, please explain the method or steps for reaching to this part.

Comment: What is exactly tour doubt on that? Maybe how can we guess that manipilation?

Comment: Yes, how can we guess that manipulation?

Comment: He basically wrote the numerator in the form of $c_1*$denominator$+c_2$, and obtained $c_1$ and $c_2$ by comparison.

Comment: I tried it, but there is no trigonometric term in the N. Please write a solution if you were able to solve it.

Comment: @Zenix The trick is aimed to use integration by parts of course it not seems so obviuos to see but of course in this way the solution is straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the shorthands $s= \sin x$ and $c=\cos x$, along with
$$s’= c, \>\>\> c’=-s, \>\>\>s^2+c^2 = 1$$
to reexpress the integrand

\begin{align}
 & {\dfrac{x^2+(n-1)n}{(x\sin x+n\cos x)^2}} \\
=&\ \frac{x^2+(n-1)n}{(xs+nc)^2} 
= \frac{x^2(s^2+c^2)+(n-1)n(s^2+c^2)}{(xs+nc)^2} \\
=& \ \frac{[xs+(n-1)c](xs+nc)-[(1-n)xs+xc](ns-xc) }{(xs+nc)^2}\\
= & \ \frac{xs+(n-1)c}{xs+nc}-
\dfrac{[(1-n)xs+xc](ns-xc)}{\left(xs+nc\right)^2} \\
= & \ \frac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac{n s-x c}{x s+n c} \right) 
= \frac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac{n\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+n\cos x} \right) \\
\end{align}

Thus

$$\int {\dfrac{x^2+(n-1)n}{(x\sin x+n\cos x)^2}} 
= \dfrac{n\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+n\cos x} +C$$

Comment: Interestingly, dividing the final fraction's numerator and denominator by $n\cos x$ converts it to $\frac{\tan x-x/n}{1+\frac{x}{n}\tan x}=\tan(x-\arctan\tfrac{x}{n})$.

Comment: @J.G. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3854130/760219) for the same integral but a different approach I took which shows why your observation is true.

Comment: How did you figure out the split in the third step?

Answer (score 4):

$$x\sin x+n\cos x=\sqrt{x^2+n^2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}\sin x+\frac{n}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}\cos x\right)$$$$=\sqrt{x^2+n^2}\cos \left(x-\arctan(\frac{x}{n})\right)$$

$$\int {\dfrac{x^2+\left(n-1\right)n}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}}dx=\int\frac{x^2+n(n-1)}{(x^2+n^2)\cos^2\left(x-\arctan(\frac{x}{n})\right)}dx$$

Put $$t=x-\arctan(\frac{x}{n})\Rightarrow\tan t=\frac{\tan x-\frac{x}{n}}{1+(\tan x)(\frac{x}{n})}=\frac{n\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+n\cos x}$$

and$$ \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x^2+n(n-1)}{x^2+n^2}$$

$$\int {\dfrac{x^2+\left(n-1\right)n}{\left(x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}}dx=\int\frac{x^2+n(n-1)}{(x^2+n^2)\cos^2\left(x-\arctan(\frac{x}{n})\right)}dx=\int\sec^2t \;dt$$$$=\tan t +c=\frac{n\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+n\cos x}+c$$

Comment: (+1)  that's very nice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your teacher is taking

$$u=\dfrac{1}{x\sin\left(x\right)+n\cos\left(x\right)}$$

$$v'=x\sin\left(x\right)+\left(n-1\right)\cos\left(x\right) \implies v=n\sin x-x\cos x$$

then by parts

$$\int uv' + \int u'v=uv$$